# Best way to keep track of facebook session

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Started using the Facebook Javascript library, question that's been on my mind, is how to I keep track of of which user is using my app.

What I mean is if one user signs up for my app, but then logs out of facebook, and another user uses the same browser/comp and goes to my app, what's the best way to handle this and sync it up with my server, so I know that a new user has signed up.

FB documentation is pretty crappy. This is more like a best practices kind of question.

Comment: Maybe if you can focus your question a little more, we could give you a less general answer. The Facebook api can be a little confusing at first. What exactly do you want to handle / sync on the server? Each loading of your app is authenticated individually. You can run FB.login. This makes sure the user is logged in and has granted permissions to the app. If not, it asks them to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample application (with documentation) that describes the best practices that you're looking for:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/samples/canvas/